# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "masters_user" already exists

Tags: django

I was trying to solve something min my db and mistakenly deleted the `django_migrations` table. Now when I run the migrate command it says:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "masters_user" already
> exists

How can I solve this without dropping the entire Database?

Comment: Do you know till which migration is applied? Or are all migrations applied?

Comment: In your django app there should be a folder named `migrations`. Please list the python files in that directory in your question. Also look inside the files and try to guess which of these migrations are applied.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--fake` flag to mark the appropriate migrations as applied. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake):

> Marks the migrations up to the target one (following the rules above)
> as applied, but without actually running the SQL to change your
> database schema.

This means that you first need to figure out / know what migrations are applied and then run the command appropriately.

If you know all the generated migrations are applied simply run:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Otherwise use the app label and specific migration name. Example: for an app with the name `xyz` whose migrations are applied till `0005` you will run:

```
python manage.py migrate xyz 0005 --fake
```

Comment: I faked the migrations but after that I tried to run normal migrations but it said no changes detected

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate --fake`? My answer clearly mentions to do that only "If you know all the generated migrations are applied". If you had run `python manage.py makemigrations` and generated some new migrations that were not applied to the database then they are also marked as applied now. First run `python manage.py migrate <appname> zero --fake` to go back to the state of no migrations being marked as applied and figure out which migrations are actually applied first.